# Lazy load Stylesheet with Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I would like to lazy load CSS via a `<link>` for my React app that is built with Webpack 2. I understand that with `style-loader` you can have `import 'foo.css'` be inlined in a `<style>` tag but I'm looking for a solution that allows for it to use a `link` tag that can lazy-loaded, much like the new `import()` does for code splitting with React Router.

Is there an existing loader that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a custom HTML template with [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin). You'll have access to all the assets that have been produced with the compilation and can reference the one's your interested with via `link` tags in the output. The next important bit would be to use [`extract-text-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) to configure Webpack to emit separate stylesheets in the assets.

Alternatively, if you'd like to work with forward-facing tech, you can mix in [`offline-plugin`](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin) and use a service worker for pre-loading assets the user might need. This might be helpful if you have trouble splitting your stylesheets, as you can simply revert to letting Webpack figure out how to split your application into chunks (CSS sources included) and the plugin will make sure these are prefetched in advance.

Comment: I got the extract text part down, however I don't know how the get the view to load the necessary `<link>` tag along with the JS. We're using PHP on the back-end if that makes a difference.